# A function to find whether a bit is on, with type char*

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to write a function that receives a char* pointer and an index and checks whether the bit in the index is on.

i got somthing like that:

```
int bitIsOn(char *ptr, int index){
    return (ptr[index/8] & (1<< (index%8)));
}
```

note: I need to use c90.
I am getting the following error message: error: invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'int')

How can I avoid type collision here

Comment: What type collision?

Comment: use size_t or unsigned as `index`

Comment: Use unsigned everywhere... Bit operations with signed values are toying with UB...

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] and copy-paste it into the question to show us. Then copy-paste the full and complete build log into the question, and add a comment on the actual line where you get the errors. The code you currently show should not lead to the error you claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unsigned data for bitwise operations. Use standard definition `CHAR_BIT` instead of magic number 8 (it is defined in `limits.h` header file).

```
int checkbit(const void *data, const size_t index)
{
    const unsigned char *udata = data;
    return udata[index / CHAR_BIT] & (1 << (index % CHAR_BIT));
}
```

If you want to return `0` or `1` you can use double logical **`NOT`** operator:

```
return !!(udata[index / CHAR_BIT] & (1 << (index % CHAR_BIT)));
```